# Reverse icon view order in Finder

Tags: finder, sort

When you press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Finder to bring up the options for the current folder and change what you sort the files by (in my case Date Created), is there any way to reverse the order?

Rather than seeing the newest files at the top, I'd rather see them at the bottom. How could I reverse the order?

Answer (score 1):

After pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, be sure the box is checked under show columns for the parameter you would like to sort by.  Then, in the Finder window, just clicking on the title of the column that you would like to sort by (in your case Date Created) will toggle through the different ways to sort by that parameter.

EDIT: This, unfortunately, only works on List View.

Comment: He's an icon view though...

Comment: This is list view only, i.e. not an answer. I'm looking for the same answer in 2023.